# Why do apps (Musical.ly, Instagram, etc...) use press-and-hold for video?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, usability-testing

I'm really trying to understand it because a simple tap to start and tap to end works as well, but I don't have to focus on holding it down.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess.

Tap to start + Tap to end = 2 interactions (finger down and up 2 times).

**Press & hold = 1 interaction** (finger down and up once).

This could make sense in an app which main purpose is to watch a lot of content (short videos among others).

Answer (score 1):

In whatsapp hold is to record audio.
According to me the main reason is to make task easier like chatting while having non text messaging.

> You need to hold as long as you want to record.Hence removing the pain of starting then recording and then pausing and then sending.